# How do I send a long JSON string via a GET/POST request in IE8?

Tags: javascript, php, json, internet-explorer-8, get

I have a long JSON string that I want to send from the front-end to PHP on the back-end, but it doesn't seem to work in IE8 because the string exceeds the 2,048 character limit.
The request gets cut off regardless of whether I use a GET request or a POST request.

Are there any ways to get around this limitation?
Thank you.

---

Edit: To save time reading, the solution is to use POST instead of GET. POST was in fact working, but I had another error in my code, which led me to believe that it wasn't working.

Comment: You could split it up into multiple requests, or change the format of the json so that it is smaller.

Comment: If I split it up, what's the best way to put it back together on the back-end?

Comment: Don't think there really is a "best" way. you would have to temporarily store them, for example in the session, and then put them together when a final request comes in with a flag stating that it's the last one. Or you can pre-calculate the number of requests you are sending and sent a pre-request that sets up the server to expect n requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just drop the support to IE8.

But, if you really want to use IE8, are you sure you can't use POST for that?

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427), the limit is on the URL length, but shouldn't affect the POST length (that's what I made of what's written there, perhaps I'm wrong; but I don't have any IE8 installed, so I can't test that).

Comment: I saw that link already, and it's stated in the first paragraph of the summary: "This limit applies to both POST request and GET request URLs."

Comment: Also, comments like "You should just drop IE8 support" don't help at all. I work for a large institution, and that's not a decision I get to make or influence in the least. If it wasn't a concern, I would not have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but it's referring to the URL (in the HTTP request, the first line "POST /url HTTP/1.1"), not the actual POST data (quoting the document, "However, the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL. ")

Comment: That's a good point. I will try that right now and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Is there an easy way to view the output of a PHP script that has been posted to?

Comment: Also, the "drop IE8 support" thing was a joke. I understand some people are required to support such old and unstandardized browsers, but still, some times it can just be a huge pain. But, to your (institution's) defense, I didn't know that IE8 is being currently used by as much as 10% of the users (source: http://theie8countdown.com/ )

Comment: Just go with `echo strlen($_POST['var']);` :) (var being the name of the value posted)

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific. I needed to see the results of the POST made via an Ajax request. Anyway, I resolved the issue, so thank you.

Comment: When you make an AJAX request, you can easily get the response: if the PHP script prints the length of the string, you can get that and display it using an alert(), or in dozens of other ways. But, if you're just doing this as a test, you might want to create an HTML form and submit it directly to the PHP page.